# bash text search: find if the content of one file exists in another file

Tags: bash, shell

Say we have two files: a.txt and b.txt. Each file has multiple lines of text.

How do I write a shell script to check if all of the content of a.txt exists in b.txt?

---

Thx for the hints guys, i didn't noticed -q will output 0 if successfully matched.

I end up with:

if `grep a.txt -q -f b.txt` ; then

else

fi

Comment: This question would would be improved if you could share what you have tried - if only to help us understand your own level of understanding of the problem.

Comment: We need to see some sample input: does a.txt exist in a in the same order? are all the *lines* of a.txt in b.txt in *some order*?

Comment: if you can sort the files, you can use `comm` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try `grep`

```
cat b.txt|grep -f a.txt
```

Comment: @GreenAsJade If could delete all the `\n`of a.txt and b.txt,that maybe will work,but how to do it?

Comment: no need for `cat`, `grep` can read from a file: `grep -f a.txt b.txt`

Comment: I think `grep -f <patternfile>` will only show you if SOME patterns from the patternfile match, but not ALL. An alternative is to sort the files using `sort -u` and then use `comm -23 a.txt b.txt`, which would produce an empty output if there are no lines that are in a.txt, but not b.txt.

Answer (score 2):

Using grep

```
grep -f a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution.   This will only tell you if some of the content of a exists in b, not if _all_ the content of a exists in b.

Comment: Parens will not execute a command.   Diff does not take a stream of lines as one of the sources to diff, it diffs two files.

Comment: So that's your problem which don't understand the request. My solution is better than the accepted solution. Aha .!.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will do what what you are describing:

run: `sh SCRIPT.sh a.txt b.txt`

```
# USAGE:   sh SCRIPT.sh TEST_FILE CHECK_FILE
TEST_FILE=$1
CHECK_FILE=$2

## for each line in TEST_FILE
while read line ; do

    ## check if line exist in CHECK_FILE; then assign result to variable
    X=$(grep "^${line}$" ${CHECK_FILE})


    ## if variable is blank (meaning TEST_FILE line not found in CHECK_FILE)
    ## print 'false' and exit
    if [[ -z $X ]] ; then
        echo "false"
        exit
    fi

done < ${TEST_FILE}

## if script does not exit after going through each line in TEST_FILE,
## then script will print true
echo "true"
```

Assumptions:

- line order from **a.txt** does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a loop that iterates over each line in a.txt and use grep (or some other means) to see if that line is in b.txt.   If you find any instance where it is *not* in b.txt, then you can provide the answer: not all lines match.   If you find no such instances, you can conclude that all lines match.

Capturing the output of grep using backticks would likely be useful:

```
if [`grep -v $line b.txt`==  ""]; then
```

kind of thing.

If you have specific questions about how to iterate over the contents of a file, you should ask a specific question about that, showing what you tried.

Comment: Downvote, but no explanation why?

Comment: Clearly, that's not the right answer, the if command do nothing to fix the problem