# How can I search a file for the contents of another file?

Tags: bash

Say I want to append the contents of `file_b.txt` to `file_a.txt`. But only if `file_a.txt` doesn't already contain the contents of `file_b.txt`. How would I first search the first file for the contents of the second?

So given `file_a.txt`:

```
the quick
brown fox
```

and `file_b.txt`:

```
jumped over
the lazy
dog
```

and the start of `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# make sure file_b.txt isn't already in file_a.txt, then:
cat file_b.txt >> file_a.txt
```

How can I ensure I end up with this, no matter how many times I execute `script.sh`?

```
the quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy
dog
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Do you want to append if its not already appended (at the end of the file) or if its not in there at all (anywhere in the file)?

Comment: Preferably if its not present in the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `diff`, like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

diff <(tail -$(wc -l file_b.txt | awk '{print $1}') file_a.txt) file_b.txt 
is_appended=$?
if is_appended ; then
  exit 1;  # file_b.txt has been appended.
else
  cat file_b.txt >> file_a.txt
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: May be you should use `#!/bin/env bash`. In my linux, `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a nested while loop to achieve the desired result

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

isNotReadInFile=0;

while read secondFile;do
    while read firstFile;do
        [[ "${firstFile}" != "${secondFile}" ]] && {
            isNotReadInFile=1;
        }
    done < ./file_a.txt

    (( isNotReadInFile == 1 )) && {
        echo "${secondFile}" >> ./file_a.txt;
        isNotReadInFile=0;
    }

done < ./file_b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in: [bash text search: find if the content of one file exists in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128592)
you could use

`grep -q -f file_a.txt file_b.txt`

**Full story**

```
editor cat_if_not_already_there.sh
```

**Paste in**

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=$1
file2=$2
if grep -q -f  $file1 $file2 ;
then
    cat $file1 # already contains the text
else
    cat $file1 $file2 # ok concat
fi
```

**Make executable**

```
chmod u+x cat_if_not_already_there.sh
```

**Prepare test files**

```
echo -e "the quick\nbrown fox" >file_a.txt
echo -e "jumped over\nthe lazy\ndog" >file_b.txt
cat file_a.txt file_b.txt > file_c.txt
```

**Expect `cat` to be executed**

```
./cat_if_not_already_there.sh file_a.txt file_b.txt 
the quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy
dog
```

[OK]

**Expect `cat` not to be executed**

```
./cat_if_not_already_there.sh file_c.txt file_b.txt 
the quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy
dog
```

[OK]

**Question to the audience**

- Does `./cat_if_not_already_there.sh file_c.txt file_a.txt` perform like expected?
- Does `./cat_if_not_already_there.sh file_b.txt file_b.txt`  perform like expected?
- Does `./cat_if_not_already_there.sh file_a.txt file_c.txt`  perform like expected?