# Test if ALL The Contents of One File exist in a Second File

Tags: linux, awk

I have found a few examples on stackoveflow on how to do this but none of them work for me.

[bash text search: find if the content of one file exists in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128592/bash-text-search-find-if-the-content-of-one-file-exists-in-another-file)

I want to test whether ALL the contents of one text file exists **in the same format/block/style** somewhere in a second file and if not add the contents of SRC >> $TGT.

If I execute these commands manually in the console, then it returns the contents of $SRC:

```
SRC="mytextfile1.txt"
TGT="mytextfile2.txt"

grep -F -f $SRC $TGT

cat $TGT|grep -f $SRC
```

And this returns nothing:

```
grep $SRC -q -f $TGT
```

And this keeps appending each time it is executed:

```
function append {
  f1=$(wc -c < "$SRC")
  diff  -y <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v "$SRC") <(od -An -tx1 -w1 -v "$TGT") | \
  rev | cut -f2 | uniq -c | grep -v '[>|]' | numgrep /${f1}../ | \
  grep -q -m1 '.+*' || cat "$SRC" >> "$TGT";
}
```

So how can I do this so that it can then be tested in an if statement ?!

## EDIT

Here's an example of the file contents:

**$SRC File**

```
text 1
text 2
text d
text e
text f
text g
```

**$TGT File Before Modified**

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 4
text a
text b
text c
```

**$TGT File After Modified**

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 4
text a
text b
text c

text 1
text 2
text d
text e
text f
text g
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks, but the input is the content of text file SRC, the TGT is the contents of text file $TGT, I simply want to test whether the contents of $SRC exist in $TGT, I am not sure if the actual text contained in either files will effect the tests ??

Comment: You might consider using some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database

Answer (score 4):

I would use perl's `index` for this:

```
if ! perl -0 -we '
    open my $f1, "<", "mytextfile1.txt";
    open my $f2, "<", "mytextfile2.txt"; 
    exit( index(<$f2>, <$f1>) == -1 )' 
then
    cat mytextfile1.txt >> mytextfile2.txt
fi
```

The key here is `-0`, which makes the `<>` operator read the entire file instead of just one line. Note that the logic is somewhat convolutee.  If `index` returns -1, the content is not matched and perl returns non-zero, which the shell treats as failure.  So the if condition is inverted.  It seems more natural that perl succeeds when the content matches, but perhaps it would be cleaner to use `!=` and and remove the outer inversion.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this and got: "readline() on closed filehandle $f1 at -e line 4.
Use of uninitialized value in index at -e line 4."

Comment: Probably not opening the file.  Try `open my $f1, "<", "mytextfile.txt" or die "mytextfile.txt: $!"`.  Probably will want to put the paths in variables to avoid the redundancy.  Perhaps a typo has mis-spelled the path.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, based on your logic(explained by OP in comments, that all contents of Input_file src should be present in same order in Input_file tgt) try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR,$0]
  val1=(val1?val1 ORS:"")$0
  next
}
((FNR,$0) in a){
  count++
  val2=(val2?val2 ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(count==length(a)){
     print val1 ORS val2
  }
}
'  file_src file_tgt
```